# windows command line multiple commands

Tags: windows, cmd

I am opening 3 cmd windows in different colours to help me distinguish between servers etc. These commands are in a `.bat` file.

```
start cmd /k color 4C
start cmd /k color 5D 
start cmd /k color 2A
```

What I need to do is have them open up at a specific location but I can't seem to get it to chain commands.

How can I `cd` in to some folder structure immediately after starting a cmd window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `&`:

```
start cmd /k "color 4C & cd \"
```

You have to quote the commands now, otherwise the `&` is consumed by the outer command prompt (e.g. the one running the batch file) rather than the newly launched one.

---

You also have another option - so far as I'm aware, a newly launched command prompt inherits the same current directory as the command prompt that launches it. So you could change your batch file to:

```
cd \location1
start cmd /k color 4C
cd \location2
start cmd /k color 5D 
cd \location3
start cmd /k color 2A
```

Comment: Inheriting the current directory worked as expected and is perfect for my use case. Thanks.

Comment: In most contexts you can embed quoted commands inside in outer quote: `cmd /k ""prog 1.bat" % "prog 2.bat""`

Answer (score 1):

```
start "" /d "c:\foldera" cmd /k color 4C
start "" /d "c:\folderb" cmd /k color 5D 
start "" /d "c:\folderc" cmd /k color 2A
```

Comment: Explanation...?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in a batch file.
For 1st cmd prompt, provide the directory structure in place of "cd\". same goes for 2nd and 3rd cmd prompt at lines "d:" and "e:".

```
start cmd /k color 4C
REM following line for c:\ directory for 1st prompt
cd\

start cmd /k color 5D 
REM for any other directory for 2nd prompt
d:

start cmd /k color 2A
REM for another directory for 3rd prompt
e:
```